# read -p command (input) inside the while loop

Tags: while-loop

I am trying to read multiple inputs from user using while loop.

I tried below

while
do
  read -p "Enter Server Names : " multi_act
done

'read -p' command is not working inside the while loop, How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed as below

exec 5< file1

while read <&5 a; do
  echo before
  read var
  echo after
done
exec 5<&-

its working like a charm.